# Why droppable and draggable of jQuery are not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Can someone tell me why is this second if statement condition is met.

Here is the code

```
$("#car").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if (!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (counter >= 40 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#win').text(winner +' '+ 'stars' + ' ' + 'earned' + ' Completion time' + ' ' + counter + ' seconds');
            }
        }
    }
});

// for droppable...
$("#carDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#car",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#car")){
            $(this).addClass("correct");

            ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
            $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){

            });
        }
    }
});
```

I checked the length of `.correct` and `.drop` using alert box and the length of `.correct` was 8 and the length of `.drop` was 5. But when i drag an image and drop it then the second if statement was working, it doesn't make sense. [**Here is fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/lawnyan/remaak5k/). It didn't work in fiddle. I think the framework in fiddle has a problem.

Comment: It would be great if you can be specific to what exactly you want . can you make a small demo of your problem , instead of copy pasting all the codes in jsfiddle.. I think all are reluctant to go through the whole code. Thats the reason you did not receive any answer till now

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the draggable's `stop` event be fired *before* the droppable's `drop` event? That would explain why there is no `.correct` class yet causing that statement to evaluate to 'undefined' == 'undefined' and hence `true`.

Comment: i put alert box after the if statement and checked the length of both class its 8 and 5

Comment: I tried removing the add class correct in droppable's drop and the if statement doesnt work. It means the droppable's drop is fired first

Comment: Surprisingly, this is the third time I am seeing this same question this week. Is it part of an assignment?

Comment: yes because no one is answering. Well it's working but i need to explain the code. This is the only part that i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your second condition in the if statement in parentheses, like this:

```
if (counter >= 40 && ($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length)) {
```

This is because `$([selector]).length` is effectively `true`

Comment: if statement is still working. It's not suppose to work

Comment: maybe try `console.log([values you want to check])` insteald of `alert()`.  It interrupts less and lets you watch the numbers as they change...

Comment: Do you have the developer tools open in your browser?  Can you see the console?  It won't do a popup the way `alert()` does.